# Ad Banner Moving Out of Position, Showing Out of Order

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad, adbannerview

I have an AdBannerView inside my game, but it keeps showing randomly even though I set it to hidden, it pops from the bottom pushing the view up.

Here's the code I have thus far in GameScene:

```
var iAd = ADBannerView()

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        iAd.delegate = self
        iAd.hidden = true
        iAd.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin

        view.addSubview(iAd)

}

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        if (!isStarted){  // <- If game has started

            iAd.hidden = false
        } 
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

        print("Ad Fail")
        iAd.hidden = true
    }

func newGame() {

iAd.hidden = true
}

func gameOver() {

iAd.hidden = false
}
```

Sometimes the ad shows during gameplay, sometimes it shows at the top, other times at the bottom.

**My questions are:**

1. How do I position it at the top?
2. How do I make it so that it stops appearing during gameplay?
3. How do I make it stop pushing the view up?
4. How do I make it stop showing if it failed to load (it currently does show)

**MORE INFO:** I tried this code in ViewController, but ended up with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1: You have set the frame property to position the banner ad:

```
iAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height - iAd.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width, iAd.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it keeps appearing at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Sorry, that was code for the bottom banner add. Try iAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, iAd.frame.size.height)

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've created an `ADBannerView` in Interface Builder in addition to including `self.canDisplayBannerAds` somewhere in your project.

The `ADBannerView` displaying on the bottom of your devices screen is created by `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

If you have included `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in your project you need to remove it.

As for hiding the `ADBannerView` when it fails to receive an advertisement, you need to implement the `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods: [ADBannerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/index.html). Then, in `bannerView(_:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:)` you'd set your `ADBannerView`'s `alpha` property to `0`.